# Use Xcode with Docker (cross-compiling)

Tags: xcode, docker, cross-compiling

Now I know this might sound weird, but I have a library that is distributed with Docker, but I want to use my IDE, Xcode.

Has anyone ever attempted to use (cross-compiling) Xcode with a software running on docker?

My needs are the simplest: compile, link, run, debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could share the data via a volume, but Xcode itself needs to run on a Mac and Docker needs to run on Linux, so you would be limited to sharing networked data.

Comment: Thanks @ldg, that much I know. However, Xcode can cross-compile, that's why I have hopes. Also I updated the question mentioning that I want to cross-compile.

Comment: If you're using the gui, it needs to be on a Mac, the code can be on a shared volume.